# Create a CLI with Thor for a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface, bundler, thor

I'm creating a gem that gives the weather connecting to APIs, i also created tests and class methods, now i want to add a command line interpreter (CLI).

> As the bundler site tutorial for create gem, i'm trying to do it with
>   [Thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor)

### I have this in `/bin/wizer` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

require "wizer/cli"

Wizer::CLI.start
```

### This in `/lib/wizer/cli.rb`

```
require 'thor'
require 'wizer'
module Wizer
  class CLI < Thor
    desc "hello world", "my first cli"
    def self.hello
      "Hello world"
    end
  end
end
```

### this on `wizer.gemspec` file

```
  spec.add_runtime_dependency "thor"
```

### And this on `Gemfile`

```
gem "thor"
```

See full gem [here](https://github.com/vmvwebworks/wizer)

Comment: sorry - uhh what's the problem here?

Comment: The Cli don't works, unable to see any CLI method.

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: bin/wizer: línea 3: require: orden no encontrada
bin/wizer: línea 5: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `ARGV'
bin/wizer: línea 5: `Wizer::CLI.start(ARGV)'

Comment: @MarcosR.Guevara please edit your question and add the erorr, so people new to the question don't have to read through all the comments. thx!

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here is that the `bin/wizer` file is not interpreted by Ruby.  Instead Bash is used, which cannot handle Ruby code (or anything else that is not a Bourne-like shell script, for that matter).

To fix that, change the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line (i.e. the first line in the file starting with `#!`) to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```